# Android SharedPreference Variable not stored

Tags: android, string, variables, sharedpreferences, store

---

I'm trying to store a variable value using sharedPreference , the problem is whenever I return back it's always NULL even though I'm sure i assigned a value to it before quitting 
(My Application takes user number and and send a verification code and checks if it's true or not,if it's true then Check variable is stored as true )

```
public class Verify extends Activity {

    TextView Number;
    EditText numf;
    TextView codet;
    EditText codef;
    TextView vcs;
    Button verify;
    Button numOK;
    ProgressBar pb;
    TextView vs;
    String cs;
    TextView vr;
    TextView checkSave;
    TextView textViewShowTime;
    String check;

    int code;
    int min = 00000;
    int max = 99999;
    private CountDownTimer countDownTimer; // built in android class
    // CountDownTimer
    private long totalTimeCountInMilliseconds; // total count down time in
            // milliseconds
    private long timeBlinkInMilliseconds; // start time of start blinking
    private boolean blink; // controls the blinking .. on and off
    long seconds;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.verifiy_activity);
         Number = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Number);
         numf = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.numf);
         codet = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.codet);
         codef= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.codef);
         vcs = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.vcs);
         verify = (Button) findViewById(R.id.verify);
         numOK = (Button) findViewById(R.id.numOK);
         pb = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.pb);
         vs = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.vs);
         vr = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.vr);
         checkSave = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.checkSave);
         textViewShowTime = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvTimeCount);

         final SmsManager sm = SmsManager.getDefault();
         checkGSM();
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "1"+check, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

         //OK button Start
         numOK.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if(seconds==0)
                {
                 setTimer();
                 startTimer();



                 Random r = new Random();
                 code = r.nextInt(max - min + 1) + min;
                 cs=String.valueOf(code);
                 //sm.sendTextMessage(Number.getText().toString(), null,cs, null, null);

                 pb.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);



                 Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), cs, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }



            }



         });

         //Verify Button Start
            verify.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                 public void onClick(View arg0) {
                     vcs.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                     pb = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.pb);
                     codef= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.codef);
                     vcs = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.vcs);
                     vr = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.vr);
                     if(!(codef.getText().toString().equals(cs))&&codef.getText().length()!=0)
                       {
                           vcs.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                           vcs.setText("Wrong Verification Code,Try Again");
                           //pb.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                           codef.setText("");
                           callCheck();


                   Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), cs, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                       }

                else if(codef.getText().toString().equals(cs))
                {

                    callCheck1();
                    vr.setTextColor(Color.GREEN);
                    vr.setText("Verified");
                     pb.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                     textViewShowTime.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);                    
                    checkSave.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "2"+check, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                     Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                           "hes"+ check, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();    
                 setCheck("true");
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "3"+check, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                } 

                 }  
                });     

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                       "4"+ check, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();




            codef.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

                public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

                }
                public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub


                }
                public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                        int after) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                }
            });


            //check verification code
            codef.setOnFocusChangeListener(new OnFocusChangeListener() {          

                public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
                    if(hasFocus==true)
                    {   


                    }
                    else
                    {                   
                        //codef.getText().length()!=0
                        //vcs.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        /*if(!(codef.getText().toString().equals(cs))&&codef.getText().length()!=0)
                           {
                               vcs.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                           vcs.setText("Wrong Verification Code,Try Again");
                           pb.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                           Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), cs, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                           }

                        else if(codef.getText().toString().equals(cs))
                        {
                            vr.setTextColor(Color.GREEN);
                            vr.setText("Verified");
                             pb.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        }*/
                    }




                }
            }); 



            //Verify Button End

    }
    public void setCheck(String x)
    {
        check=x;
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "5"+check, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
    public void checkGSM()
    {
        if(vr.equals("Verified"))
        {
        check="true";
        }
        else
        {
            check="false";
        }


    }
    public void reset()
    {
        countDownTimer.cancel();
    }


    private void setTimer() {
        int time = 5;
        if(countDownTimer==null)
        {

            totalTimeCountInMilliseconds = 60 * time * 1000;
        }
        else
        {
            reset();
            totalTimeCountInMilliseconds = 60 * time * 1000;

        }




    }

    private void startTimer() {


        countDownTimer = new CountDownTimer(totalTimeCountInMilliseconds, 500) {
            // 500 means, onTick function will be called at every 500
            // milliseconds

            //@Override
            public void onTick(long leftTimeInMilliseconds) {
                seconds = leftTimeInMilliseconds / 1000;

                textViewShowTime.setText(String.format("%02d", seconds / 60)
                        + ":" + String.format("%02d", seconds % 60));
                // format the textview to show the easily readable format
            } 

            @Override
            public void onFinish() {
                // this function will be called when the timecount is finished
                textViewShowTime.setText("Time up!");
                textViewShowTime.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            }

        }.start();

    }



    //Check Function Start
            public void callCheck1()
            {
                // Creating alert Dialog with one Button

                AlertDialog alertDialog1 = new AlertDialog.Builder(
                        Verify.this).create();

                // Setting Dialog Title
                alertDialog1.setTitle("Phone Number Saved");

                // Setting Dialog Message
                alertDialog1.setMessage("Your Phone Number Was Saved Successfully");


                // Setting OK Button
                alertDialog1.setButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        // Write your code here to execute after dialog
                        // closed
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                "You clicked on OK", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                });

                // Showing Alert Message
                alertDialog1.show();
            }






    //Check Function Start
        public void callCheck()
        {
            // Creating alert Dialog with one Button

            AlertDialog alertDialog1 = new AlertDialog.Builder(
                    Verify.this).create();

            // Setting Dialog Title
            alertDialog1.setTitle("SMS verification");

            // Setting Dialog Message
            alertDialog1.setMessage("Wrong Verification Code");


            // Setting OK Button
            alertDialog1.setButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    // Write your code here to execute after dialog
                    // closed
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            "You clicked on OK", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });

            // Showing Alert Message
            alertDialog1.show();
        }
        public void savePreferences2(String key, boolean value) {
            SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());   
            Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();       
            editor.putBoolean(key, value);
          editor.commit();
     }
        public void savePreferences(String key, String value) {
            SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());   
            Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();       
            editor.putString(key, value);
          editor.commit();
     }

    public void loadSavedPreferences() {

            SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
            SharedPreferences sharedPreferences2 = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());



          String name = sharedPreferences.getString("storedAct","xx");
          check=name.toString();
          Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "6"+check, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
          if(check.equals("true"))
                  {
              vr.setText("Activated");

            //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
            //      "hello"+check, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();  
                  }
          else
          {
              vr.setText("Still");
          }

        /*  if(name!=UserNumber)
          {
          nfield.setText(UserNumber);

          }
          else
          {
              nfield.setText(name);
          }
           */
        }
        @Override
        public void onStart(){
            super.onStart();
          loadSavedPreferences();

        }
        public void onPause()
        {
            super.onPause();
            savePreferences("storedِAct",check);

        }
        public void onResume()
        {
            super.onResume();
            loadSavedPreferences();
        }
        @Override
        public void onStop(){

            super.onStop();
            savePreferences("storedِAct",check);

        }

        //End Save Settings On Close

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, for storing settings, use:

```
public void savePreferences(String key, String value) {
    // We need an Editor object to make preference changes.
    //"mySettings" is the name of settings file, and MODE_PRIVATE means that (from the docs):
    //the created file can only be accessed by the calling application (or all applications //sharing the same user ID).
    SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences("mySettings", Activity.MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
    editor.putString(key, value);

    // Commit the edits!
    editor.commit();
}
```

And to read:

```
public void loadSavedPreferences() {
    // Restore preferences
    SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences("mySettings", Activity.MODE_PRIVATE);
    check = settings.getString("storedAct", "false");

    //rest of the code
}
```

Please also check in onPause() and onStop() key name you're using to save the prefs. It's "storedAct", but for some reason it displays weirdly here, and in my editor, and in your loadSavedPreferences(), your key is "storedAct", but it shows correctly, so it might be an issue where your keys don't match :) Also, save your prefs in onPause() only, remove it from onStop() and load it in onResume() (remove from onStart()).

Answer (score 0):

First, are you sure you use the same key to store and retreive the value?
(That can seems stupid but just to be sure...)

Then you can also try to use this.getSharedPreferences(String name, int mode)
with this beeing your activity and name, any unique name for your preferences (like your application full name)

Answer (score 0):

You must remove the call to savePreference() in activity's onStop(). The variable is probably null at that point.
Try a log output at that point to check the value of the string.